# QGIS/GRASS Watershed Analysis output cell size issues

Tags: gis, qgis, grass

Gooday,

As my first post I offer a humble apology if this is such a basic question as to make any of you cringe. I feel like I have exhausted my search skills and read through the QGIS documentation frequently and thoroughly.

My problem is with any of the hydrology analysis in GRASS through QGIS. I have a GRASS mapset that uses a 30m resolution DEM for my area. The extent of the mapset is set to include only the DEM (ie. no whitespace or no-data areas) and yet when I run r.fill.dir, r.basin or r.watershed I get back an image that has a resolution of nearly 73xxmetres. I am most used to ArcGIS where in the hydrology tools the user can define the working environment and set the output resolution to match the input resolution. Is there anyway to set that in GRASS or am I missing a basic step somewhere? I feel like I set up GRASS correctly as other non analytical map work is working fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sincere regards,

Grant McGee

Comment: Just FYI: You might get better answers for this particular question on the GIS Stackexchange. http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps this question can be removed since it was asked and discussed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/qgis-dem-output-cell-size-does-not-match-dem-input-cell-size (for the record, it seems that g.region raster=inputmap -a helped)